# Why I can't install quicklisp? ("Package QUICKLISP-QUICKSTART does not exist")

Tags: windows, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I've installed Emacs and SBCL, and I've already set up the environment variables. I've also downloaded quicklisp, but I can't get it to work (I'm using Windows 8).

I load it:

```
c:\home>sbcl ~~load quicklisp.lisp
```

And then, after I type:

```
* (quicklisp-quickstart:install)
```

I get the following obscure error:

```
debugger invoked on a SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {240866C1}>:
  Package QUICKLISP-QUICKSTART does not exist.

    Stream: #<SYNONYM-STREAM :SYMBOL SB-SYS:*STDIN* {22402A19}>

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

I've googled this "Quickstart does not exist" error, but there's nothing. I'm a Python programmer and I'm really wanting to learn Lisp, and this error is just way too cryptic for me to deal with at the very beginning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your loading command,

```
sbcl ~~load quicklisp.lisp
```

should be

```
sbcl --load quicklisp.lisp
```

Hyphens, not tildes.  (This isn't just SBCL, mind you;  it's the convention for just about all UNIX style command line arguments.)

This doesn't cause any kind of error because, as [Xach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170927/xach) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924989/why-i-cant-install-quicklisp-package-quicklisp-quickstart-does-not-exist/25925149#comment40584475_25925149) in the comments, SBCL passes arguments it doesn't understand to the program as part of **sb-ext:*posix-argv***.

Comment: SBCL passes any arguments it doesn't understand to your program as part of `sb-ext:*posix-argv*`.

Comment: What you say is correct but even with the hyphens I get a similar error message.